# Including a non-composer PHP project in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to use [this PHP project](https://github.com/onetsp/RecipeParser) RecipeParser in a Laravel project. Aa far as I can tell, it can't be loaded with Composer. It doesn't have any Composer info in the readme, and I can't find it on Packagist either.

I've tried downloading the folder to my `/App/` folder and adding it in the controler like this:

```
include app_path() . '/RecipeParser/bootstrap.php';
```

But it cannot be found.

I've tried adding the folder in composer like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/RecipeParser"
    ],
....
```

and running `composer dump-autoload` but again it cannot be location.

I've tried adding:

```
use OneTsp\RecipeParser;
```

and many variations at the contoller, but doesn't help.

The code I am trying to call it with is

```
$recipe = RecipeParser::parse($html, $url);
```

Does it need to be added in `config.app` somewhere? Is there something specific about this pcakage which means it needs to be included differently? And is there a way to just load it directly from Github,so it gets updated, etc? Normally I can find these in Composer, is there a reason this package isn't?

many thanks

Comment: to use composer with this, then you'll have to add a `composer.json` file defining the classmap. Preferably, you should fork the project and add namespaces to all the classes too.

Comment: OK, if it can't be used with Composer. Does anyone have any ideas as to how it can be included normally? And used with the `$recipe = RecipeParser::parse($html, $url);` line?

Answer (score 0):

After some google, I found [relayfoods/recipe-parser](https://packagist.org/packages/relayfoods/recipe-parser) (composer based PHP library for parsing recipe data from HTML) same like you require.

Composer command: `composer require relayfoods/recipe-parser`
Usage:

```
$recipe = RecipeParser::parse($html, $url);
print_r($recipe);
```

This should work for you.